# Getting error 'ExecuteFunction only supports stored procedures that have a return type' when calling a stored procedure using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

In my .Net application using Entity Framework I have added a SP to my entity schema. I call my SP like so

> ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<**ReturnTypeObject**>("StoredProcedure",
> param1,param2,...);

When I run this code I get error

> ExecuteFunction only supports stored procedures that have a return
> type.

My SP includes multiple table joins and insertions into temp tables, ending in a select from a final table like so

```
SELECT 
some properties...

FROM #TempTable2
WHERE Rank1 = @ParameterRank 
AND Rank2 = 1


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable2
END;
```

Some of the properties in the final select like the Rank1 and Rank2 do not exist on the **ReturnTypeObject** , and I am wondering if that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `ExecuteStoreCommand`, which does not expect any return (except "rows affected", which will not apply here)

Answer (score 0):

I found out my solution. In the 'Model.edmx' in which the SP is registered, in the 'Model Browser' tab I had to find the SP and set it's return type to the expected object, since by default it is 'none'.